# Endless connection initialization between QPID CPP 0.20 and Java client AMQP 1.0

Tags: qpid

I am running the Qpid 0.20 CPP broker (AMQP 1.0 compliant) and trying to send JMS messages with a Java application.

- what's working is when the AMQP 0-10 client and the `org.apache.qpid.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory` class are used (see [first Java example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/qpid/trunk/qpid/java/client/example/src/main/java/org/apache/qpid/example/))
- what's **not** working is when the AMQP 1.0 client and the `org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory` class are used (see [second Java example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/qpid/trunk/qpid/java/amqp-1-0-client-jms/example/src/main/java/org/apache/qpid/amqp_1_0/jms/example/)): the client goes into an endless thread loop and never actually sends the message.

Since the [Windows Azure documentation](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-US/develop/java/how-to-guides/service-bus-amqp/) explicitly mentions the use of the `org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory` class could it be that the Qpid 0.20 CPP broker doesn't support the AMQP 1.0 Java client? Given that the connection url (`http://guest:guest@localhost/test?cliendId='test-client'`) in the AMQP 1.0 example is invalid, I don't know if the code is runnable at all.

Does anyone know if the setting CPP broker - Java AMQP 1.0 client really works?